# Volley requestQueue in Singleton returns null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-volley

I am making a network request with Volley and I am using but which was working very well until suddenly it started throwing Null pointer exception on the requestQueue.

```
class VolleySingleton(context: Context) {

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var newInstance: VolleySingleton? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context) =
                newInstance
                    ?: synchronized(this){
                    newInstance
                        ?: VolleySingleton(context).also{
                        newInstance = it
                    }
                }
    }

    private val requestQueue: RequestQueue by lazy{
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context) // throws NullPointer exception
    }

    fun<T> addToRequestQueue(req: Request<T>){
        requestQueue.add(req)
    }
}
```

I have tried to initialize it like this

```
private val requestQueue: RequestQueue =
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context) // throws NullPointer exception
```

but it won't work still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `context.getApplicationContext()` instead of `context`.

```
// Add a request (in this example, called stringRequest) to your RequestQueue.
VolleySingleton.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this in the Application class which is global and stays in scope for the life of the app session.  This is in Java, but you might see something I'm doing that you are not.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    /**
     * Log or request TAG
     */
    public static final String TAG = "MyApp";

    /**
     * Global request queue for Volley
     */
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    /**
     * A singleton instance of the application class for easy access in other places
     */
    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        // initialize the singleton
        sInstance = this;

    }

    /**
     * @return MyApplication singleton instance
     */
    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * @return The Volley Request queue, the queue will be created if it is null
     */
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
        // created when it is accessed for the first time
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }


    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue, if tag is specified
     * then it is used else Default TAG is used.
     * 
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

        VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue using the Default TAG.
     * 
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TAG);

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Cancels all pending requests by the specified TAG, it is important
     * to specify a TAG so that the pending/ongoing requests can be cancelled.
     * 
     * @param tag
     */
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

Then, you call this in your other Activity code after creating your request object:

```
MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am going to try this too